# Android MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE Intent Returning Null data.getData()

Tags: android, camera, null

I am trying to invoke the Android camera using the following code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        if (uri != null) Log.d("", uri.toString());
        else Log.d("", "uri is null."); // ...but why? It should hold the image URI.
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}
```

According to the documentation:

"**MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT** - This setting requires a Uri object specifying a path and file name where you'd like to save the picture. This setting is optional but strongly recommended. If you do not specify this value, the camera application saves the requested picture in the default location with a default name, specified in the returned intent's Intent.getData() field."

This is not my experience. For me, this code returns null for `data.getData()`. I have also experimented with setting the output Uri but that gave me a whole different set of issues...

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: On what device was this? I know I had to make some workarounds depending on the device manufacturer / os version... `data` was indeed `null` in some cases.

Comment: A rather obscure ToughShield R500+ rugged phone:
http://www.tough-shield.com/device/r500-2/

Comment: If `data` itself is `null`, I used an pseudo-hardcoded string that I know this device was saving the picture to...

Answer (score 1):

have a look at this code

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)  {
   if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);

    //you can create a new file name "test.jpg" in sdcard folder.
    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + File.separator + "test.jpg");
    try {

        f.createNewFile();
        //write the bytes in file
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        // remember close de FileOutput
        fo.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (f.exists()) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Image Found : "+f.getAbsolutePath().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }else{
          Toast.makeText(this, "Image Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


 }
}
```

and your intent should be

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

Comment: On some devices that I encountered, sometimes `data` itself is null.

Comment: in that case You have to tell the camera, where to save the picture and remeber the uri yourself:

Comment: Yep, exactly ; using `Intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, yourCustomUriToRemember)`.

Comment: I think the bitmap returned in the Intent is only a thumbnail.

Comment: @shkschneider if you are satisfied with my answer kindly accept it

Answer (score 1):

As long as your users can use any camera app you'd better to create temp file and put URI to EXTRA_OUTPUT. The specification is not clear and not every application follows it.
Here's method I'm using for reserving file:

```
public static File reserveTempFile(String directory, String extension) throws IOException {
    final File pathFile = new File(directory);
    if (!pathFile.exists()) {
        final boolean result = pathFile.mkdirs();
        if (!result) {
            throw new IOException("Can't create directory");
        }
    }

    File file;
    do {
        String fileName = Long.toString(System.nanoTime());
        if (Utils.isNotEmpty(extension)) {
            fileName += "." + extension;
        }
        file = new File(pathFile, fileName);
    } while (file.exists());

    return file;
}
```

Comment: I have tried creating a `mNewPhoto` File object and calling `intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mNewPhoto.toURI());` but when I return from the camera, `mNewPhoto.exists()` is false. I'm flummoxed.